# Why can’t I see a full list of people who liked my Facebook post?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I have a post with 6.9 thousand likes and I'm trying to invite them all to like my page, but it stops showing the rest of the list once I get about 700 people down. I can't scroll down any further, but there are thousands more people I need to invite. What's going on? How can I see the rest of the people?